# SQL: How to select where date field is specific month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to select all invoices entered in a specific month.

The 'entry_datetime' field in the database is in the format of '2013-02-19 14:47:42'.

I'm using MySQL.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    entry_datetime > 2012/12/31 AND entry_datetime < 2013/02/01
```

Unfortunately it's not returning any results but I can see a qualified invoice via phpMyAdmin.

Please can you tell me what is wrong with the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    invoices
WHERE
    entry_datetime > '2012/12/31' AND entry_datetime < '2013/02/01'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've amended my code as suggested and it is still not selecting the invoice with entry_datetime '2013-01-19 14:49:38'

Comment: are you sure ? that query will grab the data between 31 Dec 2012 until 01 Feb 2013

Comment: I copied and pasted the entry_datetime (2013-01-19 14:49:38) from phpMyadmin directly. I'm suspecting that it's the time portion that might be causing this to fail?

Comment: Sorry, there was an issue in the fields I was selecting. I'm using encryption, so it's hard too see the raw data and the query I showed here was simplified for the question. Thanks. Your method worked.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
   invoices
WHERE
    entry_datetime between '2012/12/31' AND '2013/02/01';
```

And if you want to get result of a specific month then use function like:
month() as:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
   invoices
WHERE
   MONTH(entry_datetime)=12;
```

where 12 is month mumber

Answer (score 0):

Since the dates in the where clause are not enclosed in quotes, MySQL assumes that it's a mathematical formula/equation. So it evaluates 2012/12/31 as something like 5.4086.